# Selenium click next button - nothing happens when attempting to click button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to press the next button on this webpage until there are no pages left, but it seems my code is not able to find the next button as the script stops running immediately.
https://doffin.no/Notice?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10

**The code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='MY_PATH',options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
page_source=driver.page_source
while True: 
        try:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*@id="content"]/div/article[3]/div[11]/ul[1]/li[13]/a').click()
            print("Navigating to next page")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('Last page reached')
            break
        [Do something]
```

**My output**

When I run this code I get "Last page reached" immediately.

FYI, the button I want to press is the one with two triangles, as shown in the screenshot below. If I'm not mistaken, the xpath is '//*@id="content"]/div/article[3]/div[11]/ul[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyZRe.png)/li[13]/a'

[image]

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I have not been able to solve the issue by looking at those questions. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: did you click the wrong button?

Comment: I don't think so - I used the "Copy -> Copy Xpath" option on the webpage so I guess it should be the right xpath (?)

Comment: Try this instead `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "pager-action").click()`

Comment: @MJO sure, but in the screen shot, it looks like the "go to last page" button is greyed, like it was clicked.

Comment: @SuperStew Yeah, it was just in the screenshot that the go to last page is greyed. I was probably hovering it as I was taking the picture

Comment: @SulemanElahi It seems that despite clicking, the webpage does not change pages, e.g., I remain in page 1, despite "Navigating to next page" is shown. Do you know why that happens/how to fix it?

Comment: @MJO iterate though page numbers in URL instead of via XPATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is evident that there are 100 pages. So why not just iterate through that?

Change

```
while True: 
        try:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*@id="content"]/div/article[3]/div[11]/ul[1]/li[13]/a').click()
            print("Navigating to next page")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('Last page reached')
            break
        [Do something]
```

to

```
for i in range(100):
   driver.get('https://doffin.no/Notice?pageNumber='+str(i+1)+'&pageSize=10')
   [Do something]
```

Comment: I was able to make it work with your approach above (iterate with url and keeping the while loop), but this would also work - thank you!